# Exclude Char from Python For

Tags: python

I get this array values from `request.POST`:

```
array = [1,2,3]
```

When iterating in a `for` like this:

```
for item in array
```

I get `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','`

I need to save those values in a database table.

What could be the best way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: More code please./Más código por favor.

Comment: So you have a url like ``http://example.com/myapp?array=1,2,3``? Please, be explicit when asking questions. "My input looks like X, I want YY output. How do I get there?"

Comment: Please be more specific. What framework do you use? Please post the exact content of `array` and tell us what `type(array)` yields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're getting a string, not an array. In that case, you can do this:

```
import json
array = '[1, 2, 3]'
for item in json.loads(array):
    print item
# Prints 1, then 2, then 3
```

Alternatively, if you just want to skip everything that isn't an integer (though this is not recommended), you can use a `try/except` block in your for loop:

```
array = '[1, 2, 3]' # Or array = '1, 2, 3', whatever the case may be
for item in array:
    try:
        print int(item)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

This will silently ignore anything that isn't an integer.

Comment: then it would raise at the `[`

Comment: Ah, yeah you're right. We need more info from the OP!

Comment: Probably it's just `'1,2,3'`, but yes, we do need more info.

Comment: In that case `json` wouldn't be able to parse it unless you add the bounding brackets.

Comment: Thank you @HuuNguyen !! Your solution worked, I didn't realize that I was getting a string not an array so I converted the string to a Python List like this: `array.split(",")`. As moooeeeep said, using `json.loads` stopped the loop at the first `[`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments, sorry for the lack of code

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure where the problem is. I did this:

```
>>>array = [1,2,3]
>>>for item in array:
...    print(item)
...
1
2
3
>>>
```

No error message. Is there something else going on in your program?